# How to separate buffer results in C

Tags: c, linux, codeblocks

I receive data from a TTL device every 5 seconds. I am using Raspbian(like Debian) because I have a Raspberry Pi. With the usage of Cutecom emulator I receive these:

```
+PARAM: 44 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (048)
MACHINE_1:(T=23.32,HR=43.45,Dw=10.19,VCC=3.85V)
```

after 5secs

```
+PARAM: 44 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (048)
MACHINE_1:(T=23.32,HR=43.49,Dw=10.21,VCC=3.85V)
```

etc.

I am trying to implement this in C using Codeblocks. I have a function which opens the serial port, a configure function and the following function which reads the buffer. I used a for loop for 2 loops only.

```
int learn_port(int fd)
{
   int n;
 for (int x = 0; x<2; x++)
 {
  char buff[300];
  memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
  n=read(fd,buff,300);
  printf("%s\n", buff);
 }
}
```

Now, my problem is that I have 3 results every 5 secons like

```
+PARAM: 44 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (048)
MACHINE_1:(T=23.32,HR=43.45,Dw=10.19,VCC=3.85V)
+PARAM: 44 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (048)
MACHINE_1:(T=23.32,HR=43.49,Dw=10.21,VCC=3.85V)
+PARAM: 44 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (048)
MACHINE_1:(T=23.32,HR=43.49,Dw=10.21,VCC=3.85V)
```

after 5 secs

```
+PARAM: 44 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (048)
MACHINE_1:(T=23.32,HR=43.52,Dw=10.22,VCC=3.85V)
+PARAM: 44 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (048)
MACHINE_1:(T=23.32,HR=43.52,Dw=10.22,VCC=3.85V)
+PARAM: 44 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (048)
MACHINE_1:(T=23.32,HR=43.52,Dw=10.22,VCC=3.85V)
```

My first thought was to change the size of the buffer. To make it similar to the size of the first line only. It works but sometimes the device sends me more characters and then I have terrible results. What can I do to separate these 3 results/5sec to 1result/5sec like Cutecom's results? If you need more details I can send you.

Comment: In reality I have a for(;;) loop because I want the loop not to stop. So, in every loop it reads the buff and with the printf it sends me back the results. Is there any better way for this?

Comment: In cutecom I receive it 1 time per 5sec

Comment: Are you sure that the sender doesn't send it thrice?

Answer (score 1):

My guess: You don't check the return code from `read`.

Could it be that `read` returns nothing the second and third times round the loop but the buffer still contains the old data?